Is there a way to change the default remote distro used when calling command line vscode `code` commad
I recently changed the name of my default wsl distro name using the Windows registry. Now when I call vscode's command line command code . it opens the folder in the wrong distro. Does anyone know how to change the default --remote location when calling code

To resolve my issue I ended up doing:
wsl --shutdown in Powershell
Upon reopening Ubuntu and running code . it opened to the default distro set on wsl

Open WSL conf file
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

Inside nano, enter
default=desired_WSL_distro

Replace desired_WSL_distro with your desired distro name
Save the changes by pressing ^o

Thank you so much for answering, unfortunately it did not work.

Sorry for not answering your question properly. I have edited my answer and hope it helps.
